# method to remove users from files

Tags: java, client

this code can find the client but cant remove it. client name - "rafael"
i just cant remove the client and i dont know why, i tried some codes but didnt work, can you guys help me?

//this delets clients

```
public void EliminarUtilizador(){
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dados = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            dados = _ficheiro.lerDados();
            // the line is an array that haves date stored on the file
            //0-nome 1-pass ...
            for(ArrayList<String> linha : dados){
                Utilizador a = new Utilizador(linha);
                if("Rafael".equals(linha.get(0))){
                    System.out.println("Client found");

                }
            }  
          }


    ----------------------
    //This reads the file

      public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lerDados(){
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dados = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            Scanner s;
            try{
            s = new Scanner(new File(nomeFicheiro));
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                return dados;
            }
            String dado;

            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                dado = s.nextLine();
                dados.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dado.split(","))));
            }
            s.close();
            return dados;
        }
```

Comment: *i tried some codes but didnt work* where is the code that you tried? Why didn't it work.  Surely you have to write to the file.  BTW did not you write the same question half an hour ago?

Comment: i dont know the code to remove, i tried dados.remove linha.remove etc

Comment: search for how to write to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use iterator to iterator through the list. Once you find the item, you can remove using iterators method. Below is sample code.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> itr  = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String str = itr.next();
        //remove item based on some condition.
        itr.remove();
    }
```

Comment: how does that remove from a  file?

Comment: you need to write back the result to the file.

Comment: i just cant see it

Comment: You did not mention to delete record from a file. You just mentioned that your code is not deleting the record. For that you should use iterator in place of for each loop. Now in order to write list in a file - what issue are you facing? Please share your code. Did you try to write to a file? There is no reason to downvote the answer.